# Button click not registering

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

I have an Xcode 5 button problem.

I create a number of button programatically on a `UIViewController` and then want to register clicks on these buttons. I use `NSLog` to track the clicks but it seems that no clicks are registered in the log.

Can anyone help please?

The ultimate aim to to segue to next `UIViewController` on each button click, but was just testing to see if button clicks were registered first.

Here is how I create the buttons in `viewDidLoad` (only 1 shown).
NOTE: the `if-statement` used only to check which buttons were pressed in previous view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.tagNumber ];

    if (self.tagNumber == 1)
    {
        hotelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        hotelButton.tag = 1;
        hotelButton.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, 300.f, 100.f);

        UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage1.png"];
        [hotelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:hotelButton];

        // Add targets and actions
        [hotelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    }
```

}

And here is how I check for button clicks

```
- (void) buttonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Button %i clicked", hotelButton.tag);
}
```

NOTE: I also tried the following:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *) button
{
    NSLog(@"Button %ld clicked", (long int)[button tag]);
}
```

But that gave an error "undeclared selector `buttonClicked`" in my `viewDidLoad` pointing to action@selector):

```
[hotelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
[hotelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

---

From Apple Docs:

```
UIControlEventTouchUpInside
A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

UIControlEventTouchUpOutside
A touch-up event in the control where the finger is outside the bounds of the control
```

And keep this method:

```
- (void) buttonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Button %i clicked", hotelButton.tag);
}
```

Comment: Well spotted, totally missed that. Must have hit enter on the wrong one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
[hotelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and pass the sender,

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button %i clicked", [sender tag]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try and change outside to inside,

```
[hotelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have modified your if condition. Please follow :-

```
if (self.tagNumber == 1)
    {
        hotelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        hotelButton.tag = 1;
        hotelButton.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, 300.f, 100.f);

        UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage1.png"];
        [hotelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
hotelButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
hotelButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
        [hotelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:hotelButton];

    }
```